# Web to lead True/False Considerations?

Tags: rest, web2lead, checkbox

Are there any special considerations when submitting data for a Checkbox field through Web to lead endpoint?

When I submit a lead with checkbox value True, it accepts the lead.

When I submit a lead with checkbox value False, it does not accept the lead.

Of course web-to-lead always shows status 200. Is there a different syntax for indicating false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web-to-Lead always processes leads asynchronously. The form that is submitted is (usually) always successful, which simply means the Lead has been placed in a queue for asynchronous processing in the org when resources are available.

In normal HTML/HTTP standards, a checked box is submitted with the form data, and an unchecked box is *not* submitted. In other words, when the box is checked, the payload should look like:

```
oid=00DXXXXXXXXXXXX&00NYYYYYYYYYYYY=1&last_name=Demo&retURL=myserver.com/thanks.html
```

And when the box is not checked, it should look like:

```
oid=OODXXXXXXXXXXXX&last_name=Demo&retURL=myserver.com/thanks.html
```

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Thank you